# how can I make clickable url in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

I am trying to build OS-X core data based app. In one of the entities, I am storing an URL ex. (www.somesite.com/somepage/someindex.php)

Using binding, I am successfully displaying the URL in the `NSTableView`. I would like however that URL to be clickable, and when clicked, browser to fire up and open the page. I have done some research, and I have found some solutions, for example:

[Clickable url link in NSTextFieldCell inside NSTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765047/clickable-url-link-in-nstextfieldcell-inside-nstableview)

also:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1487/_index.html

but they both look outdated, first one is six years old, while the second is last updated on Jan. 2005

Anyone can provide easier & faster way how to achieve this? I didn't expected that I will have to write bunch of code just to make simple link to work to be honest... I am coming from web development world, where those kind of things can be sorted out withing few seconds, while here seems to be totally different story....

Any help will be appreciated.

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSTextView` and implement its delegate. There is a demo:

```
// MyCellView.h
@interface MyCellView : NSView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;

@end

// ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyCellView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    MyCellView *cell = (MyCellView *)[tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" owner:self];

    cell.textView.delegate = self;
    [cell.textView.textStorage setAttributedString:[self makeLinkAttributedString:@"This is a test: www.somesite.com/somepage/someindex.php"]];

    return cell;
}

- (NSAttributedString *)makeLinkAttributedString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableAttributedString *linkedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    [detector enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
        if (match.URL) {
            NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSLinkAttributeName: match.URL };
            [linkedString addAttributes:attributes range:match.range];
        }
    }];

    return [linkedString copy];
}

#pragma mark - NSTextViewDelegate methods
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView clickedOnLink:(id)link atIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex {
    // The click will be handled by you or the next responder.
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: `UITextView` already has a native data detectors for links in `dataDetectorTypes` property, there is no need in manual detecting with `makeLinkAttributedString` method in your code.

Comment: You are right, but `setAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled:` works only when the NSTextView is editable.

Comment: Uhmm, I thought it's working in readonly only, not editable? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes I believe so, I saw this: http://travisjeffery.com/b/2013/11/url-linking-in-a-non-editable-nstextview/

Comment: This guy is absolutely wrong, for sure. I turn this in IB a thousand times and it works fine while not editable and not working when editable. Searching in SO shows that people experience the same behavior.

Comment: Are you using `UITextView` or `NSTextView`?

Comment: hmm. i could to swear i did this in NSTextView, but must be confused to UITextView, you are right. My bad.

Comment: Can anyone help me to understand how can I implement the above solution? Should I remove NSTableView that I use altogether and use NSTextView instead? I have some other fields there, so I need the NSTableVeiw...and yes my NSTableView is editable. Any step by step instrucion of how can I implement this solution will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: @user2417624 No, you don't need to remove the `NSTableView`. You should create a separate cell and nib file, then you can register the cell to `NSTableView`. Here's a full tutorial although Swift: http://nscurious.com/2015/04/08/using-view-based-nstableview-with-swift/.

Comment: Still trying to implement the above code. I didn't create .nib file, since when you create NSView, that option is not available (checkbox is gray)...so I have no idea how to connect the IBOutlet, code display bunch of errors....starting from this line [super viewDidLoad];...so you get the picture...

Comment: @user2417624 You can also create the view programmatically instead of xib.

Comment: I really get lost in this. One more night working on this without any result. Can you please describe the steps involved in more detail? I prefer to use xib instead of creating the view programatically, in hope that I will understand what I am doing.

Comment: I have created a demo at Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0vqati0ulyeqd7/TestClickableNSCell.zip?dl=0, I hope this will help you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) in your tableviewcell. It supports powerful link detection.

Comment: I will definitely take a look on this, even that I would prefer native solution (if there is any)...thanks anyway.